# What is the right sequence in GROW CANNON from Eyezmaze?

Tags: grow-cannon

What is the right sequence of shots in [GROW CANNON](http://www.eyezmaze.com/eyezblog_en/blog/2011/01/grow_cannon.html) mini game from Eyezmaze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct sequence of distances is:

> - 4
> - 5
> - 6
> - 4
> - 3
> - 4
> - 1
> - 2
> - 3
> - 5